# update database value from '0' to '1' in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment this HTML form is actioned to `complete.php` like so:

```
<form action\"includes/welcome_complete.php\" method=\"post\"><input type=\"submit\" class=\"welcome-submit3\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Finish ->\" id=\"submit\"/></form>
```

I am then trying to get `complete.php` to run a MySQL query, I want it to update the column `initial_prompt` in the database from `'0'` to `'1'` for the user and then redirect.

For some reason it redirects but doesn't update the value in the database.

Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong. thanks.

`complete.php`:

```
<?php
    require_once('includes/session.php');
    require_once('includes/functions.php');
    require('includes/_config/connection.php');

    session_start();

    $result1 = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET initial_prompt='1' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    if($result1) 
    { 
        $_SESSION['dashboard_intro']="<div class=\"user_settings_box_home\"><strong>Welcome to your new profile</strong> - This is your Dashborad.</div><div class=\"infobox-close4\"></div>"; 
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: What variable type is initial_prompt?

Comment: The `mysql`-extensions is not maintained for a long time now and will be flagged as deprecated with 5.5. Use `PDO_MySQL` or `MySQLi`. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Comment: can you show your mysql error?

Comment: echo out the string to see what you get

Answer (score 2):

How is it able to redirect is something I'd like to learn.

The problem appears to be in your `form` definition. Here's the actual HTML code(unless I'm mistaken about the question).

```
<form action="includes/welcome_complete.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="welcome-submit3" name="submit" value="Finish ->" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the redirect works and you are checking for success in the sql query my first guess is that $_SESSION['user_id'] is not what you expect it to be, try echoing it

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your trying to add `'1' (string)` instead of `1 (integer)` to your table

Comment: I think it'd cast that back to an int

Comment: I would suggesting that you echo out the query just before running it to see if it's really what you were expecting. My guess is that the user id isn't making it into the query properly.